# VueJS 3 - Different behavior between computed/ref from ‘@vue/composition-api’ and ‘vue’

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I noticed really strange behavior between nested computed/ref from @vue/composition-api and vue.

```js
const options = ref([{
  val: computed(() => 10)
}])
```

**Print value with VueJS 2**

```js
console.log(options.value[0].val.value) // 10
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shenron/q7wxon95/13/

**Print value with VueJS 3**

```js
console.log(options.value[0].val) // 10
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shenron/q7wxon95/10/

**Use case**

My use case, I have two components. A custom Select and a custom Option. The custom select provide a list of options, and each option register itself.

Here the type of the list of options:

```js
type Option = { 
  value: string;
  label: string;
  root: Ref<HTMLElement>
};
const options: Ref<Array<Option>> = ref([]);
```

The custom select to access to `root` has to do:

```js
// VueJS 3
options.value.forEach((opt) => console.log(opt.root)) // not opt.root.value

// VueJS 2
options.value.forEach((opt) => console.log(opt.root.value))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shenron/q7wxon95/

I’m a bit confused, is it normal?

Thank you very much.

Original question:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/different-behavior-between-computed-ref-from-vue-composition-api-and-vue/112717